# Check if elements has the same parent (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a system that puts all images inside paragraph-tags, as such:

```
<p>
  <img src="..." />
</p>
```

So I wrote a function to move the images out of the paragraph tags. It looks like this:

```
moveImagesOutOfPtags() {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('p > img');

  Object.entries(images).forEach(entry => {
    let value = entry[1];

    if( value.parentNode.nodeName === 'P' || value.parentNode.nodeName === 'p' ){
      value.parentNode.outerHTML = value.parentNode.innerHTML;
    }
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work if there are two images inside the same p-tag, as such:

```
<p>
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</p>
```

... Since the parent is removed/rewritten/overwritten with the `value.parentNode.outerHTML = ...`-line, for the first image. So when it gets to the second image in that p-tag, then it throws the error:

> Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.

Any suggestions on a good way to solve this?

Comment: Interesting way of using `Object.entries()` to iterate over a `NodeList`... But there's no need for it because a `NodeList` already has a `.forEach()` method

Comment: Please explain the link between "I'm working on a system that puts all images inside paragraph-tags" and "So I wrote a function to move the images out of the paragraph tags"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to achieve with DOM manipulating methods instead of setting HTML strings, like this:

```js
function moveImagesOutOfPtags() {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('p > img');
  images.forEach(img => {
    const parent = img.parentElement;
    // Insert the image as a previous sibling to the paragraph
    parent.parentElement.insertBefore(img, parent);
    if (parent.children.length === 0) {
      // Remove the empty paragraph
      parent.remove();
    }
  });
}
moveImagesOutOfPtags();
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="...">
</p>
```

You don't have to check the parent, since the query will select the images wrapped in a paragraph only, just insert the image as a previous sibling of the parent. Then check if the parent is empty, and remove if needed.

Answer (score 0):

use id for every paragraph-tags and check the previously modified id with current one . i don't think this is the best way but this will let the job done.

html contents

```
<p id = "p_id_1">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</p>
<p id = "p_id_2">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</p>
```

script will be

```
moveImagesOutOfPtags() {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('p > img');
  var p_id='';
  Object.entries(images).forEach(entry => {
    let value = entry[1];

    if(p_id != value.parentNode.id && (value.parentNode.nodeName === 'P' || value.parentNode.nodeName === 'p' )){
      value.parentNode.outerHTML = value.parentNode.innerHTML;
      p_id = value.parentNode.id;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just catch the error and not carry on like this:

Try this:

```
moveImagesOutOfPtags() {
  document.querySelectorAll('p > img').forEach(entry => {
    const value = entry && entry[0]; // catches error if p has been replaced and doesn't continue.
    if(value){ // you don't have to test if parent is p tag, you've already determined that with your direct child selector p > img
      value.parentNode.outerHTML = value.parentNode.innerHTML;
    }
  });
}
```